# integrate springmvc and sendgrid?

Tags: java, spring, sendgrid

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I am getting the following exception when I tried to add sendgrid dependency

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
```

Comment: Post whole exception with "caused by" parts.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have below dependency in pom.xml

Try to use the latest `com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind`.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can any one have sample example of springmvc and sendgrid to send mails?

Comment: WARNING: Exception processing loader WebappLoader[/logisticsservice] background process
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\postcourse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\logisticsservice\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: it means you already have the jackson-databind dependency with 2.5.3.

Comment: http://springjavatutorial.blogspot.com/2013/10/spring-mvc-with-send-grid-for-mail_29.html